# how does "auth" in firebase work

Tags: firebase, jwt, firebase-authentication

how does firebase remember authenticated users across browsers and what happens behind the scenes when we are authenticating using jwt (JSON web tokens)
What data will auth in firebase have ?

Comment: Firebase supports many identity providers: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-providers. Which one are you asking about? Keep in mind: the broader the scope of your question, the less likely someone is to answer.